# _com_ptr_t::CreateInstance

Tags: c++, com

Есть два приложения, App1 и App2. App2 - стартует из первого по средствам _com_ptr_t `m_pApp2.CreateInstance(CLSID_App2);`. App1 запускается батником т.к. требует ряд параметров. Допустим App1 каким-то образом может упасть или его можно убить через диспетчер задач. Проблема в том, что если запускать батник повторно из проводника, то App2 подхватывается то, которое уже запущено и это правильное поведение, но если тот же батник запускать из планировщика задач, то при старте App1 создаётся новый инстанс App2.

Почему при старте из планировщика задач запускается новый инстанс App2? Как можно настроить планировщик, чтоб этого не происходило? Или как по-другому инициализировать App2, чтобы всегда гарантированно подхватывался уже запущенный процесс App2?

Comment: Посредством `CreateInstance` создается только COM-объект, как там запускается приложение из этого контекста не ясно. Если из-под планировщика задач оно запускается по-другому, то дело может быть в запуске из-под другой учетной записи или с другими привилегиями.

Comment: В диспетчере задач видно, что учётка одна и та же, попробую выяснить на счёт привилегий, спасибо!

Comment: В диспетчере задач в колонке UAC virtualization при запуске из проводника пишет disabled, а при старте шедулером - not allowed. В обоих случаях приоритет нормальный. Если в шедулере ставить опцию "запускать с повышенными привилегиями", по App1 стартует с below normal, но App2 всё равно с нормальными